# pyspark - attempting to create new column based on the difference of two ArrayType columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like so:

```
+-----+----+-------+-------+
|name | id | msg_a | msg_b |
+-----+----+-------+-------+
|    a|   3|[a,b,c]|[c]    |
|    b|   5|[x,y,z]|[h,x,z]|
|    c|   7|[a,x,y]|[j,x,y]|
+-----+----+-------+-------+
```

I want to add a column so that anything in `msg_b` but not in `msg_a` is surfaced.
E.g.

```
+-----+----+-------+-------+------------+
|name | id | msg_a | msg_b | difference |
+-----+----+-------+-------+------------+
|    a|   3|[a,b,c]|[c]    |NA          |
|    b|   5|[x,y,z]|[h,x,z]|[h]         |
|    c|   7|[a,x,y]|[j,x,y]|[j]         |
+-----+----+-------+-------+------------+
```

Referring to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359666/difference-between-two-dataframes-columns-in-pypark), I've tried
`df.select('msg_b').subtract(df.select('msg_a')).show()`
which works, but I need the information as a table, with `name` and `id`

Doing this:
`df.withColumn("difference", F.col('msg_b').subtract(F.col(''msg_a'))).show(5)`
yields an `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Not sure if there is a separate function for performing this operation, if I'm missing something glaringly obvious, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `UDF`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

@udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def subtract(xs, ys):
    return list(set(xs) - set(ys))
```

Example

```
df = sc.parallelize([
   (["a", "b", "c"], ["c"]), (["x", "y", "z"], ["h", "x", "z"])
]).toDF(["msg_a", "msg_b"])

df.select(subtract('msg_b', 'msg_a'))

+----------------------+
|subtract(msg_b, msg_a)|
+----------------------+
|                    []|
|                   [h]|
+----------------------+
```