# Difference between two imbalance DataFrames columns in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a followup question on top of this thread: [Difference between two DataFrames columns in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359666/difference-between-two-dataframes-columns-in-pyspark)

This time, I am looking for a way to find difference in values, in columns of two **SUBSET** DataFrame. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

df_a = sql_context.createDataFrame([(1,"a", 3), (2,"b", 5), (3,"c", 7)], ["id","name", "age"])

df_b = sql_context.createDataFrame([("a", 3), ("b", 10), ("c", 13)], ["name", "age"])
```

DataFrame A:

```
++------+---+
|id|name|age|
++------+---+
|1 |   a|  3|
|2 |   b|  5|
|3 |   c|  7|
++------+---+
```

DataFrame B:

```
+----+---+
|name| age|
+----+---+
|   a|  3|
|   b| 10|
|   c| 13|
+----+---+
```

i plan to use subtract to get the dataset

```
++------+---+
|id|name|age|
++------+---+
|2 |   b|  5|
|3 |   c|  7|
++------+---+
```

However, seems subtract does not support

- using subset comparison and return the full set of dataset

Is there any other way that i can compare 2 imbalance dataset and return the id ? or it is a must to use join for the comparison?

Answer (score -1):

(original post i tested ans related to left anti)
updated at 230727 (left anti is not a good method for None comparison)

e.g. from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

```
# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame A
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, 10001, "a"), 
  (2, 10002, "b"), 
  (3, 10003, "c"), 
  (4, None, None), 
], ["user_id", "master_key",  "info"])

# Create DataFrame B
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, "a"), 
  (2, None), 
  (3, "c"), 
  (4, None), 
], ["user_id",  "info"])

# Select the subset of columns for comparison
subset_columns = ["user_id", "info"]

# Left anti Join
result_df = df_a.join(df_b, subset_columns, "left_anti")

# Show the result
result_df.show()
+-------+----+----------+
|user_id|info|master_key|
+-------+----+----------+
|      2|   b|     10002|
|      4|null|      null|
+-------+----+----------+
```